# three.js，How to complete the animation migration of two similar bones?

Tags: animation, three.js, fbx, web-share-target

Two similar bones. The animation skeleton is a pure skeleton without SkinnedMesh and skeleton. The names are different and the levels are also slightly different. How to achieve correct animation migration and playback? I have a complete bone naming mapping table. This happened when I first tried to migrate the animation. The model is distorted. I tried to use SkeletonUtils.retargetClip to correct it but the effect was not good. How can I correct my model?

```
           const loader = new FBXLoader();

            loader.load('/static/resources/models/pg_actorcore_embed.fbx', function (model) {
                scene.add(model);
                // 加载动画
                loader.load('/static/resources/animations/blender_animation.fbx', function (anim) {
                    console.log(anim)
                    const clip = anim.animations[0];
                    clip.tracks.forEach(track => {
                        const boneName = track.name.split('.')[0];
                        if (SMPL2ACTORCORE2[boneName]) {
                            track.name = track.name.replace(boneName, SMPL2ACTORCORE2[boneName]);
                        }
                    });
                    mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(model);
                    const action = mixer.clipAction(clip);
                    action.play();
               });
            });
```

[This is the animated image loaded by the above code, and the character model is severely distorted.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7lip.png)

The following is my attempt to use SkeletonUtils.retargetClip for animation redirection, hoping to solve the problem of model distortion.

```
 const loader = new FBXLoader();

            loader.load('/static/resources/models/pg_actorcore_embed.fbx', function (model) {
                scene.add(model);
                // 加载动画
                loader.load('/static/resources/animations/blender_animation.fbx', function (anim) {
                    console.log(anim)
                    const clip = anim.animations[0];
                    clip.tracks.forEach(track => {
                        const boneName = track.name.split('.')[0];
                        if (SMPL2ACTORCORE2[boneName]) {
                            track.name = track.name.replace(boneName, SMPL2ACTORCORE2[boneName]);
                        }
                    });
                    
                    let animbones = []
                    anim.traverse(function (object) {
                        if (object.isBone) {
                            const newName = SMPL2ACTORCORE2[object.name];
                            if(newName){
                                object.name = newName
                            }
                            animbones.push(object);
                        }
                    }); 
                    let animSkinnedMesh = new THREE.SkinnedMesh();
                    let animSkeleton = new THREE.Skeleton(animbones);
                    console.log(animSkeleton)
                    animSkinnedMesh.skeleton = animSkeleton; // animbones 是从动画文件中获取的骨骼数组

                    
                    let modelskeleton;
                    model.traverse(function (object) {
                        if (object.isSkinnedMesh) {
                            modelskeleton = object;
                        }
                    });
                    const modelHelper = new THREE.SkeletonHelper(model);
                    scene.add(modelHelper)

                    // 假设 model 是目标模型，已经在场景中
                    //let targetSkinnedMesh = model.getObjectByProperty('type', 'SkinnedMesh');

                    // 使用 SkeletonUtils.retargetClip 迁移动画
                    let retargetedClip = SkeletonUtils.retargetClip(modelskeleton, animSkinnedMesh, clip,{
                        preserveMatrix: true,
                        preservePosition: true,
                        preserveHipPosition: false,
                        useTargetMatrix: false,
                    });
                    console.log(retargetedClip)
                    // 创建动画操作并播放
                    mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(modelskeleton);
                    const action = mixer.clipAction(retargetedClip);
                    action.play();
                });
            });
```

[This is an animated picture using retargetClip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6TSu.png)

It can solve the problem that the model is distorted by animation data, enable normal animation playback, and realize animation migration using similar bones.

Comment: Why does it cause distortion in the model?